# Are there frameworks available to track user activity?

Tags: c#, logging, synchronization, sql-server-ce, metrics

Before I start writing my own custom classes, I was wondering if there was a framework already out there to use.

This is for a Winform/WPF application. I will be storing things such as battery levels, WiFi strength, hard drive info, RAM info, etc. Along with those, I need to also record what the user was doing at the time such as 'logged in', 'logged out', 'clicked a certain button' etc.

I'll be persisting this information to a SqlCe database locally that eventually gets synchronized to a server for debugging/reporting.

It would be great to reuse some code already available.

Thanks for any help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what language you're using but I'm assuming .Net from the C# tag in your post. In that case you could use log4net to log user activity and whatever other useful data. It supports logging to databases along with many other formats.

Comment: Yes. I'm using c#. I already use log4net and didn't consider that either. That's another good option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Membership/Roles/Profile provider classes in .net. These .net classes are usually used for ASP.net applications but essentially they are a collection stored procedures and class libraries that allow you to track user profile and activity with a web application. There's even the ability to determine if the user is presently logged in or not.

You can use the following to create the tables and stored procedures to support the funcitonality you are looking for.

[ASP.NET SQL Server Registration Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You'll have to include a System.Web section in your app.config file with the following child nodes so your application can utilize the classes effectively. Also, yoiu'll have to reference the System.Web.Security library in you references and your "using" statements.

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="MembeshipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="Test" name="MembeshipProvider"
             type="SqlMembershipProvider" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="RoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="Test" name="RoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <profile defaultProvider="ProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="ProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider"
             connectionStringName="Test"/>
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" type="System.String"/>
        <add name="LastName" type ="System.String"/>
        <add name="Email" type="System.String"/>
        .
    .
    .
      </properties>
    </profile>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look into that and see if it contains what I need. I didn't consider that at all ;)

Comment: I ended up creating my own class that acts as a wrapper for log4Net. This seems to work fine but I question the efficiency of it right now.